# Where do I go after the prologue?

Tags: fortune-summoners

After clearing the prologue, you're told that you should investigate the Shrine of Wind in your hometown of Tonkiness, and the Weathervane Tower near Barness.

Unfortunately, there's a cranky guard who won't let me in to the Shrine of Wind, and the bridge to Barness is out (like I haven't heard *that* a thousand times!).

It vaguely seems like I ought to be able to lure the cranky guard away by mentioning the lady on the road to Barness who has a crush on him, but that option doesn't seem to come up so it's probably not the right way to go.

So, what do I do next? Is there a path somewhere that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit more running around talking to NPCs, I discovered I was half right; the lovelorn lady does play a role, but apparently the only way to this guard's heart is through his gut:

1. Go to the house next to Arche's house and talk to the old lady inside; she will tell you that her son (the cranky guard) forgot his lunch, and ask you to take it to him.
2. Go to the cranky guard, and give him his lunch. He will then complain about the fact that guys who stand around guarding old ruins all day don't meet many ladies.
3. Go to the broken bridge just before Barness, and talk to the lady there. She will write a letter to the guard, which is not for the eyes of little girls such as yourselves.
4. Return to the guard with your illicit words, which will elicit some surprised words from him. He then rushes off to be with his one true love, after warning you to not enter the ruins.
5. Enter the ruins.